# Else no ejecuta código luego de llamado a sql

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP. Todo se ejecuta a la perfección y realmente no hay ningún error. Sin embargo el error aparece al momento de ejecutar un último *else* tras una llamada a la base de datos. Adjunto el código completo y la parte específica en la que el código falla.

```
    <?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    include_once 'includes/templates/headeraccess.php';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
    echo 'swal("Ups!","Debes iniciar sesión para estar aquí.","warning").then( function(val) {';
    echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
    echo '});';
    echo '}, 200);  </script>';
    session_destroy();
    die();
}else{
    include_once 'includes/templates/headerlogged.php';
}

include 'php/conexion_be.php';

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], (FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

    $myuser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $use = mysqli_fetch_array($myuser);

    if($_SESSION['id'] != $id) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
    echo 'swal("Ups!","No deberías estar en esta página","error").then( function(val) {';
    echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
    echo '});';
    echo '}, 200);  </script>';
    session_destroy();
    die();
    }
}

?>
<main class="Access">
    <section class= "seccion contenedor home">
        <div class="contenedorLeft">
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="exampleInput">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $use['nombre'];?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="exampleInput">Nombre de usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{4,16}$" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo $use['usuario'];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="exampleInput">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $use['correo'];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="exampleInput">Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="No registrado" value="<?php echo $use['telefono'];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <img class="img-circle" src="img/profilepics/<?php echo $use['avatar'];?>" alt="avatar">
                        <label for="exampleInput">Avatar</label>
                        <input type="file" id="avatar" size="30" name="avatar">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar datos" name="actualizar"></input>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['actualizar'])){

            $usuario = ($_POST['usuario']);
            $correo = ($_POST['correo']);
            $telefono = ($_POST['telefono']);

            $comprobation = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND id != '$id'"));
            if($comprobation == 0){

            $type = 'jpg';
            $rfoto = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
            $name = 'profilepic@'.$id.'.'.$type;

            if(is_uploaded_file($rfoto)){
                $destino = 'img/profilepics/'.$name;
                $nombrea = $name;
                copy($rfoto, $destino);
            }else{
                $nombrea = $use['avatar'];
            }

            $sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET usuario = '$usuario', correo = '$correo', telefono = '$telefono', avatar= '$nombrea' WHERE id= '$id'");
            if($sql){
                $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'window.location.href="'.$page.'";';
                echo '</script>';
            }else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
                echo 'swal("Ups!","Este nombre de usuario ya está registrado","error").then( function(val) {';
                echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'myaccount.php\';';
                echo '});';
                echo '}, 200);  </script>';
            }
        }
        }
        ?>
```

La parte en cuestión que me genera el problema es esta:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET usuario = '$usuario', correo = '$correo', telefono = '$telefono', avatar= '$nombrea' WHERE id= '$id'");
            if($sql){
                $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'window.location.href="'.$page.'";';
                echo '</script>';
            }else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
                echo 'swal("Ups!","Este nombre de usuario ya está registrado","error").then( function(val) {';
                echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'myaccount.php\';';
                echo '});';
                echo '}, 200);  </script>';
            }
```

El problema persiste cambiando el código actual por cualquier otra variante, ya sea otro echo, un alert, un refresh, etc. Simplemente no lee lo que se incluye en este *else*. Es como si no lo leyera, como si el código no estuviera allí implementado: escriba lo que escriba resulta indiferente. No logro comprender el motivo de esto. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: la función `mysqli_query` va a devolver _true_ si el query se ejecutó correctamente y diría que  es por eso que no entra al `else`. Introduce intencionalmente un error de sintaxis, por ejemplo cambia `delete` por `delet` (sin la e), y va a devolver falso, por lo que si entrará al `else`.

Comment: Entiendo. Sin embargo la idea del código es que devuelva el else al momento en el que la persona ingrese un  nombre de usuario que ya se encuentre registrado. Pero al momento en que eso ocurre no se imprime el else, simplemente no se actualiza el campo.

Comment: Un update puede ejecutarse exitosamente sin afectar filas, diría que no está _fallando_ por la razón que tu esperas; estoy asumiendo que tienes un constraint `uinque` en el campo `usuario` y por eso esperas que no acepte duplicados. Sin embargo, ya que no _falla_, pero no actualiza ningún registro, diría que probablemente el where apunta a un `id` que no existe. Esto haría que se ejecute sin emitir mensajes de error, con lo cual la función devuelve verdadero. Sugiero que imprimas la sentencia para evaluarla visualmente. También puedes evaluar el resultado de `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, el problema era que el código iba en un else que respondia a otro condicional, no al cual yo lo añadía xP. Muchas gracias igual por tu respuesta!!